# Select an option from a ajax generated table row through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table and inside this table every row is generated using ajax.
In every row there is a select tag with an id(selectTax).
I want to make a js function that occur when this select selected.
For this i am using

```
$("#selectTax").change(function(){
  console.log("vikash");
});
```

But when i am clicking on this nothing happening.
Help me soon please.

Comment: Identifiers in HTML must be __unique__,  instead assign a common class then use Class selector and for dynamically generated elements use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Sir I also Used class in that Select but nothing happening.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", ".selectTax",function(){ console.log("vikash", $(this).val()); });`

Comment: You canoot assign the same id to more than 1 element, also try to use 'this' instead of using the id

Comment: Hi Satpal thanks alot bro. Now it is Working.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue with your code:

. Identifiers in HTML must be unique. So use `class` selector instead.

. For dynamic html, use `$(document).on()` like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function(){
  // your logic here
});
```

Comment: For dynamic html use $(document).on() thanks i learned it today.

Answer (score 0):

try this i have not added ajax code but similar to your code i have generated dynamic select tag and added its change event.

check your console for errors if any

```js
function AddSelect(){
    var select = $("<select class='content-select'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>");
    $("#content").append(select);
}

$(document).on('change', '.content-select', function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Add Select tag" onclick="AddSelect()">

<div id="content">
</div>
```